# Catchall type for Golang API response

Tags: json, api, types, struct, go

I am trying to define a struct that can hold an array of any type like so:

```
type APIResonse struct {
    length int
    data []interface{}
}
```

I want the `data` property to be capable of holding an array of any type/struct so I can have a single response type, that will eventually be serialized to json. So what I want to be able to write is something like the following:

```
someStruct := getSomeStructArray()
res := &APIResponse{
    length: len(someStruct),
    data: someStruct,
}
enc, err := json.Marshal(res)
```

Is this possible in Go? I keep getting `cannot use cs (type SomeType) as type []interface {} in assignment`. Or do I have to create a different response type for every variation of data? Or maybe I am going about this wrong entirely / not Go-like. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `interface{}` and not an array of it, and you can put whatever you want there.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I still get the `cannot use` error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with that code.

You need to use `interface{}`, not `[]interface{}`, also `[]` is called a slice, an array is a fixed number of elements like `[10]string`.

And your `APIResponse` fields aren't exported, so `json.Marshal` will not print out anything.

```
func main() {
    d := []dummy{{100}, {200}}
    res := &APIResponse{
        Length: len(d),
        Data:   d,
    }
    enc, err := json.Marshal(res)
    fmt.Println(string(enc), err)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/hdeN69HvCD)